# EF6 One-to-Variable Relations Ship?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.
I Need a solution for my FeeStructure Table. There is a "FullProgramFee" property in my Class that will save all semester fee of any Degree Program in string form. But problem is here Every Degree Program have variable number of semesters. I need to store fee for all semester separately. How can i store Semester fee in my Table.

```
public class FeeStructure
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string fullProgramFee { get; set; }
    //public string Semester vise fee { get; set; } pending.
    public int? ProgramID { get; set; }
    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need fee in string format? I do not think so. Just add one to many relationship to your DegreeProgram class `public virtual ICollection<Semester> Semesters {get; set;}`. Add Fee property to semester, but numeric. So now you can get fee of program using LINQ `var programFee = degreeProgram.Semesters.Sum(m=>m.Fee)` and

> all semester fee of any Degree Program

```
var allSemestersFee = allDegreePrograms.SelectMany(m=>m.Semesters).Sum(m=>m.Fee);
```